# Get Epoch/ Unix timestamp from Zoned Datetime in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp

I have to convert the birth date of people born in USA to Epoch and store it in database. Right now I am getting birth date from a legacy system in two different formats: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss & dd-MMM-yyyy.

How do I convert it properly with taking into account zone offset? My current code looks like this but it is having problems due to zone offset. What is proper way to go about this?

```
public class DateTimeUtils
{
    public static Instant parseBirthDateTime(String birthdate)
    {

        if (birthdate != null)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date date;

            try
            {
                date = formatter.parse(birthdate);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (!e.getMessage().contains("Unparseable date"))
                {
                    if (Logger.isErrorEnabled())
                        Logger.error(e);
                }
                formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

                try
                {
                    date = formatter.parse(birthdate);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (Logger.isErrorEnabled())
                        Logger.error(e);
                    return Instant.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00.00Z");
                }
            }

            if (date != null)
            {
                return Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime());
            }
            else
            {
                return Instant.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00.00Z");
            }
        }

        return Instant.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00.00Z");
    }

}
```

Comment: First, the clear and strong recommensdation is you stop using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. They are troublesome and long outdated, nothing you want to struggle with. Instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)

Comment: *born in USA*, that spans some 8 or 20 time zones depending on how you count. If you need too take the birth time zone into account and you don’t know which it is, I think you have an impossible task.

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse(birthdate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).atZone(yourDesiredZoneId).toInstant()`. And for the other format `LocalDate.parse(birthdate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu", Locale.US)).atStartOfDay(yourDesiredZoneId).toInstant()`. If the first one throws a `DateTimeParseException`, try the second one. You may for example set `yourDesiredZoneId` to `ZoneId.of("America/Menominee")`, obviously depending on which time zone you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In March 2014, `java.time` API supplanted the [error-prone legacy date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since then, it is strongly recommended to use this modern date-time API.

You need time-zone for each date-time value you are getting to convert them to an `Instant` from which you get the Epoch value.

Using the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, you can create a `DateTimeFormatter` with the default value for time as `00:00` and then use the same formatter to parse date as well as date-time into the `LocalDateTime`.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("[dd-MMM-uuuu[ HH:mm]][uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]")
                .parseCaseInsensitive()
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        String arr[] = {"2022-11-14 08:40:50", "14-Nov-2022"};
        for (String sdt : arr) {
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(sdt, formatter);
   
            // Assuming you have the time-zone for each value. For the demo, I
            // have used here only one time-zone.
            ZoneId zodeId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
            long epoch = ldt.atZone(zodeId).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
            System.out.println(epoch);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
1668433250000
1668402000000
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.